# Displaying number of records in continuous fashion in php paging

Tags: php, paging

I have a page which displays number of records on each page. I am displaying 5 records on each page and then next 5 on the next page and so on. Paging is working fine but the problem is on first page I'm displaying number serial wise next to each record i.e. from 1 to 5. Then on next page it should display numbers from 6 to 10 and on next page 11 to 15 and so on. But on every page numbers start from 1 to 5.
My code is below. I have tried different strategies but nothing worked. Please check code and tell me where to make changes so that it works properly. Thanks a ton in advance.

```
<div class="grid_12">
    <div class="box first round fullpage mh500 grid">
        <h2><?php echo $resource->_pageHead; ?></h2>
        <?php  $resource->displayMessage(); ?>
        <?php   
            if($resource->_recordCount > 0)
            {
        ?>
            <div class="block">
                <table class="listing" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="50" class="bdr-left">Sr. No.</th>
                            <th width="60">Name</th>
                            <th width="60">Email</th>
                            <th width="60">Address</th>
                            <th width="60">City</th>
                            <th width="60">State</th>
                            <th width="60">Phone Number</th>
                            <th width="60">Country</th>
                            <th width="60">Comment</th>
                            <th width="60">Inquiry Date</th>
                            <th width="60" class="bdr-right">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $i = 1;
                        $_SESSION['number'] = $i;
                        $perpage = 5;
                        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $resource->_table");
                        $total_record = mysql_num_rows($q);
                        $pages = ceil($total_record/$perpage);
                        $page = (isset($_GET['page']))?$_GET['page']:1;
                        $start = ($page-1) * $perpage;
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $resource->_table LIMIT $start, $perpage");
                        while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                    ?>      
                            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $res['name']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $res['email'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $res['address'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $res['city'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $res['state'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $res['p_code']."-".$res['p_num'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $res['country'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo substr($res['comments'], 0, 100);echo "...";?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $res['inquiry_date'];?></td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=delete&id='.$res['id'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this record?');">
                                        <img src="img/cross.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete"/>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    <?php
                            $i++;
                        }
            }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="paging" style="padding-left:500px;">
                <?php
                    $prev=$page-1;
                    $next=$page+1;
                    if($prev > 0)
                    {
                        echo "<a href='?page=$prev'>Prev</a>";
                    }
                    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    if($pages >= 1 AND $page <= $pages)
                    {
                        for($x=1;$x<=$pages;$x++)
                        {
                            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                            echo ($x==$page) ?"<a href=?page=$x style=\"font-weight:normal;\">$x</a>":'<a href="?page='.$x.'" >'.$x.'</a>';
                        }
                        echo "&nbsp&nbsp";
                        if($page<$pages)
                        {
                            echo "<a href='?page=$next'>Next</a>";
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope the following logic would be helpful to you, initialize a variable `$i = 0;`
Calculate the starting number of a record by the following logic,

```
 $page_num   =   (int) (!isset($_GET['page']) ? 1 : $_GET['page']);
 $start_num =((($page_num*$num_records_per_page)-$num_records_per_page)+1);
```

initialize a variable `$i = 0;`

Then inside the loop calculate the serial number like,

```
$slNo = $i+$start_num;
```

Then echo `$slNo;`

Comment: Thank you Vineesh, but I found its solution a year ago. But anyways it is not waste and I'll definitely learn from your answer while doing any such task next time.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `echo $i`; try this

```
$j= (($page-1) * $perpage) + i; echo $j;
```

Comment: Dear Synchro sir I was try to formatting but it was not formatted well because I am  new at this site. Please explain me how to use Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can go to this website and there is a simple example of pagination
http://snipplr.com/view/55519/ 
hope this works for you.
```

Comment: @sanj:- I was not looking for pagination. My pagination works fine. I was just looking for displaying serial wise numbers next to each record which are not coming from db but generated through php variable. Well, I got my issue resolved.